# How to have a form without onChange event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to provide a form that allows the user to change the size of an element. But since the element rendering is quite heavy, I do not want to use onChange here so it triggers rerendering of the whole thing each keystroke. How do I make my form only acting on submit?

The following code complains that I need an onChange event on each input field. But when would that not cause the app to rerender each time I change the input?

```
const App = (props) => {
    //const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(props.height);
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(props.width);

    const handleResize = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setWidth(value.width);
        setHeight(value.height);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleResize}>
                    <input type="text" value={width} name="width" />
                    <input type="text" value={height} name="height" />
                    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="workspace">
                <Workspace width={width} height={height} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uncontrolled inputs and read their value in the `handleResize` function.

To make the inputs uncontrolled pass `defaultValue` instead of `value`.

Like so:

```js
  const widthRef = useRef();
  const heightRef = useRef();

  const handleResize = (e) => {
    const newWidth = widthRef.current.value;
    const newHeight = heightRef.current.value;

    setWidth(newWidth);
    setHeight(newHeight);

    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

A working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ishizaka-xewyq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok both anwers work, which one is the best practice, the one with ref or the one with accessing children like @kind user showed?

Comment: If you want to keep the controlled inputs (so you can run validation for example), you can add a second set of height/width variables that will only update on form submit, but keep the first set of variables update on every onChange event

Comment: Yes I thought about the second values already, maybe it makes sense to prevent users from entering anything but numbers.

Comment: I didn't know about `e.target.children`. Looks like a clever trick but can backfire if you modify markup or change the order of the elements. I feel like using refs is a bit more safe and explicit. But tbh I'd go with additional state variables

Answer (score 1):

Form won't re-render on onChange unless you update state inside onChange. If you don't intend to do anything onChange then simply do this `onChange ={()=>{}}`

Comment: It's not about the form rerendering. It's about workspace

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `value` prop from inputs to keep it uncontrolled. You can get the input values directly from the form:

```
const handleResize = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const [width, height] = e.target.children;
    const w = width.value;
    const h = height.value;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. If I console log width, height then I get the whole input fields.

Comment: @user6329530 Well, forgot about the value. Updated the answer.

Comment: Got another answer, which one is better practice? because both seem to work

Comment: @user6329530 Using refs is a better approach, however it will be more work to do.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is called Uncontrolled Components.

Take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: Yes I found that but I didn't understand a word.